# Play video instead of downloading in node js

Tags: node.js, video-streaming

I want to create an api in nodejs, in which i will send the filename from the frontend and this file exists in the `files` folder in server.

I want to play the video placed in files folder on server side instead of download it at frontend. I searched on google about this. But didn't found anything useful.

Please tell me how can i do above?

Comment: some of this can depend on the client browser. as an example using m3u8 format, go to https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-examples-sample-streams/  links using mobile browsers vs desktop.. on my systems the desktop will download an m3u8 with the corresponding mime type while mobile safari and mobile chrome native clients will stream and play it.   so the answer can depend on other vars

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp  sometimes due to diff capabilities of diff clients , it helps to supply a variety of formats inside a media tag  ( using audio instead of video but the same applies ). All to show u need to account for a viariety of clients

Comment: @RobertRowntree, The video file will only be mp4 file.

Comment: @RobertRowntree, I want to know the code of nodejs side.